# java illegal start of expression error

Tags: java, error-handling, expression

When I tried to run the code below, an error appeared:

```
error: illegal start of expression
```

What does this error mean? How will I be able to fix it?

```
public boolean isVowel(char c) {
    if (c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u' ||) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Remove trailing `||`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a trailing or (||), remove it.